# Android: No Class Def Exception from Dependency Module

Tags: java, android, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

My application module is using a library module in the same project for various classes. There are no error shown in Android Studio, and when I build, I don't have any errors. But when it tries to access one of my classes from the library, it throws a NoClassDef exception. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Logcat output is below.

Manifest for Service (I'm using a custom SDK):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.linear.deviceservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" 
        tools:ignore="OldTargetApi" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SERIAL_PORT"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <service 
            android:name="LinearService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.project.permission.DEVICE_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.project.deviceservice.BIND"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In my main application:

```
List<PeripheralDevice> devices =
    mConfigurationManager.getConfiguration().getPeripheralDevices();
/* Send the update message with list of appropriate uris to each service. */
ArrayList<Uri> uris;
/* For each service, get the list of uris for that service. */
for (String scheme : mServices.keySet()) {
    uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for (PeripheralDevice device : devices) {
        if (scheme.equals(device.getUri().getScheme())) {
            uris.add(device.getUri());
        }
    }
    /* Send the update message here. */
    updateDevices(mServices.get(scheme), uris);
}
```

In my Service:

```
protected List<IDevice> mDevices = new ArrayList<IDevice>();
...
{
    mDevices = msg.getData().getParcelableArrayList(Messages.DEVICES_KEY);
}
```

Logcat

```
12-11 12:24:45.717 2391-2406/com.linear.service E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.project.deviceservice.Device
                                                      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.deviceservice.Device
                                                          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
                                                          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133)
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097)
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013)
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2343)
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1703)
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2034)
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
                                                          at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
                                                          at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1250)
                                                          at com.project.deviceservice.DeviceService$1.handleMessage(DeviceService.java:50)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project/deviceservice/Device
                                                          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
                                                          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2343) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1703) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2034) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314) 
                                                          at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) 
                                                          at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1250) 
                                                          at com.project.deviceservice.DeviceService$1.handleMessage(DeviceService.java:50) 
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.project.deviceservice.Device" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
                                                          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2133) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2343) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1703) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2034) 
                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314) 
                                                          at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) 
                                                          at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1250) 
                                                          at com.project.deviceservice.DeviceService$1.handleMessage(DeviceService.java:50) 
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
12-11 12:24:45.727 2391-2406/com.linear.service W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c21ba8)
12-11 12:24:45.727 2391-2406/com.linear.service E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: LinearService Messenger
                                                              Process: com.linear.service, PID: 2391
                                                              android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.project.deviceservice.Device
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2147)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2097)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2343)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1703)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2034)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
                                                                  at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
                                                                  at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1250)
                                                                  at com.project.deviceservice.DeviceService$1.handleMessage(DeviceService.java:50)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Post some of your code, where are you using the class Device?

Comment: Hey post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Elenasys post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by adding:

```
Bundle data = msg.getData();
data.setClassLoader(IDevice.class.getClassLoader());
```